# Candy machines and optimal strategy in terms of expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, optimization, recreational-mathematics, expected-value

### Problem

We have three candy machines: call them G (good), B (bad) and M (mixed) . G always gives you a candy when you put 1\$. B never gives you a candy when you put 1\$. M gives you a candy with probability $1/2$ when you put 1\$. You want a candy and you approach the three machines but you don't know which one is G, B or M. You use the following strategy. You approach a random machine. If you don't get a candy in $n$ trials, you change a machine. If you don't get a candy from the second machine in $k$ trials, you change to the remaining machine. At most, we can pay for a candy $n+k+1$ \$. We want to calculate the expected cost of obtaining a candy using this strategy. Is it the case that $k=n=1$ is the optimal strategy, i.e. yielding the least expected cost of obtaining a candy?

### Attempt of solution

Currently, my thinking is the following. Consider the indicator random variable $X_i = 1$ meaning that we pay 1\$ at stage $i$. Observe that:

- $P(X_1 = 1) = 1$ (we always pay 1\$ at the beginning)
- $P(X_2 = 1) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}$ (you pay at stage $2$ iff you don't receive a candy at stage $1$ which happens either when you choose $B$ with probability one third or you choose $M$ with probability one third and then $M$ doesn't give you a candy with probability one half)
- $P(X_3 = 1) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^2$ (similar justification as previously but keeping in mind that you consider an event of not obtaining a candy at stages $1$ and $2$)
- $\dots$
- $P(X_{n+1} = 1) =  \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^n$
- $P(X_{n+2} = 1) = \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^n$ (= the probability that we don't receive a candy at stages up to $n+1$. This could happen either when we first happen to choose B and then M, in which case the probability of not obtaining a candy in $n+1$ trials is $\frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{2}$, or when we first choose M and than B, in which case the probability of not obtaining a candy in $n+1$ trials is $\frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^n$)
- $\dots$
- $P(X_{n+k+1} = 1) = \frac{1}{6} (\frac{1}{2})^k + \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^n$

We are interested in $E(\Sigma_{i=1}^{n+k+1} X_i)$. Using linearity of expectation, we may write:

$$E(\Sigma_{i=1}^{n+k+1} X_i) = 1 + E(\Sigma_{i=2}^{n+1}X_i) + E(\Sigma_{j=n+2}^{n+k+1}X_j) = $$

$$=1 + \Sigma_{i=1}^n(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^i) + \Sigma_{j=1}^k(\frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^j + \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^n)=$$

$$= 1 + \frac{1}{3}n + \frac{1}{3}\Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2^i} + k \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{6}\Sigma_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{2^j}$$

Now, we can easily observe that when $n$ is fixed and we make $k$ bigger, $E$ also grows. This excludes strategies $n < k$ from being optimal. We can go somewhat further by observing that:

$$ \Sigma_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2^i} = \frac{1 - \frac{1}{2}^{n+1}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}}- 1 = 1 - (\frac{1}{2})^n$$

This gives you:

$$E(X) = 1 + \frac{1}{3}n + \frac{1}{3}(1 - (\frac{1}{2})^n) + k \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{6}(1 - (\frac{1}{2})^k)=$$

$$ 1 + \frac{1}{3}n + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^n + k \frac{1}{6} \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6}(\frac{1}{2})^k$$

$$6 E(X) =  9 + 2n - 2 (\frac{1}{2})^n + k \frac{1}{2^n} - (\frac{1}{2})^k$$

$$6 E(X) = 9 + 2n + (k-2)\frac{1}{2^n} - (\frac{1}{2})^k$$

This makes it clear that when you keep $k$ fixed and make $n$ bigger, $E$ grows as well. This excludes strategies $k < n$ from being optimal. So the optimal strategy should satisfy $n=k$. So let's assume that in the equation for $E$:

$$6 E(X) = 9 + 2n + (n-2)\frac{1}{2^n} - (\frac{1}{2})^n=$$

$$ 9 + 2n + (n-3)\frac{1}{2^n}$$

I will not go further now, but, at least know, it's clear for me that the right hand side of the above equation assumes minimal value for $n=1$ which yields the strategy $n=k=1$ as optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly you always want $k = 1$. If you have tried two machines and gotten candy from neither, the last one *must* be the Good one, so there's no reason not to try that next. This leaves our choice of $n$. Intuitively it's clear that this one should be 1 as well: after failing to get a candy from the machine once, it's either Bad or Mixed with probability 1/2, while both other machines are Good with probability 1/2, so those machines definitely appear more appealing. But let's make this formal.

The strategy $n = k = 1$ nets you an expected value of $5/3$ tries until you obtain a candy. Now suppose that $n \geq 2$. Write $X$ for the number of tries, and $B, M, G$ for the event that the first machine you try is the Bad, Mixed, Good one. Then:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X \mid B)}_{\geq n + 1}\mathbb P(B) + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X \mid M)}_{> 1}\mathbb P(M) + \underbrace{\mathbb{E}(X \mid G)}_{=1}\mathbb P(G)\\
&>(n+1)\frac13+ 1\times \frac13 + 1 \times \frac13\\
& \geq \frac53.
\end{align*}
$$
Here the "strictly greater than" on line 2 stems from the fact that the expected number of tries when the first machine is Mixed is actually strictly greater than 1. Thus $n = k = 1$ is optimal.

Comment: I don't see why $E(X | M)P(M)$ evaluates to $1 \times \frac{1}{3}$, for $n \geq 2$. Obviously, $P(M)= \frac{1}{3}$, but when you are dealing with $M$, $X$ can assume any value $i$ such that $1 \leq i \leq n$, each with probability $(\frac{1}{2})^i$.

Comment: Note that there is a $>$ sign in between. $\mathbb E(X \mid M) > 1$, and $\mathbb P(M) = \frac13$.

Comment: @elelel, I've changed the formatting a bit for more clarity.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, @Mees de Vries. I like your solution, because it's short compared to mine.